# "Load denied by X-Frame-Options"

Tags: url, github-pages

I'm showing [this](http://joereddington.github.io/CommuniKate/) thought a different URL using Dreamhost's tool for this, which, I understand, puts the whole site in a frame.

(This is the URL I serve from http://communikate.equalitytime.co.uk/)

My issue is that the links all try and open within the frame, even when that isn't helpful.  More to point, linking page to Github fails because "Load denied by X-Frame-Options" (which is udnerstandable).

My question is - how can I ensure that any external links that are opened within the frame, open outside the frame?

Answer (score 0):

> Dreamhost's tool for this, which, I understand, puts the whole site in a frame.

That seems somewhat bizarre, you may want to contact the host about why / how they are doing this. It seems strange that they would want to have all links in a frameset. This seems like very undesirable behavior.

> how can I ensure that any external links that are opened within the frame, open outside the frame?

The best way to do this is set `target="_top"` in the anchor elements, so you'd have to modify the HTML. For example:

```html
<a target="_top" href="https://github.com/joereddington/CommuniKate" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i> 
    <span class="network-name">github</span>
</a>
```

Alternatively you could write some JavaScript to set this on all anchor elements instead of adding it to the elements individually.